# Get an error System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled, Value Cannot be null. Parameter name: activationContext

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm getting the following exception when I try to run up my Winforms app and haven't been able to find a solution to it:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: activationContext
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=activationContext
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I've added a handler for the "unhandled error" event in the applicationevents class but it never reaches that stage and there is no source code running that I can break into and diagnose.

The application was fine until I added a user control (nothing fancy, just a standard windows user control) and then dragged it onto a form in the app (user control and form were in the same application).  The application builds and compiles without any errors or warnings but when I attempt to run it up I get the above error straight away.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be or even how I can go about investigating it?  I'm a bit stumped on this one as I'm not sure how to investigate it.  I removed the user control from the form and then I removed the user control from the application entirely but the error hasn't gone away.  In all honesty the addition of the user control might be a red herring but the problem manifested straight after adding it.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I just rolled back to the working version and went through the steps again to re-create the problem.  It's definitely adding the user control doing it.  The user control has no content or code behind - adding a new user control to the project had no effect but as soon as I dragged it from the toolbox to the form the error returned.  Removing it from the form and deleting it from the project does not fix the problem - it persists until I roll back to the previous version.

Comment: Is click-once involved? http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VisualStudio/microsoft.public.vstudio.general/2008-11/msg00115.html

Comment: Not intentionally but I've just unchecked the "enable clickonce security settings" checkbox in the security tab of the application properties and the error has gone away.  I never would have thought of looking there - to my knowledge I didn't tick that box.

Comment: Thanks for that Rene, I can't honestly say I understand why but that's got rid of the problem :)

Comment: @rene This just fixed my problem too. Why does the ClickOnce interfere? How is it at all related?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try unchecking the `Enable clickonce security settings` checkbox in the security tab of the application properties(`Projects Tab -> "Project Name" Properties-> Security Tab`).

Comment: This worked, but I'd like to know why I was getting the error in the first place.

Comment: I tried that, it even works, and I was able to deploy the app to a test server. But then installation fails (manifest errors). How did you deploy your application?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue as you @andreas. I wouldn't be able to compile after publishing (publish failed to work anyway). I got the error above and now it's resolved after disabling ClickOnce security. But still my installation fails. Did you ever figure this out? And what does ClickOnce's security settings have to do with all of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Build -> Clean Solution instead. I don't know why this isn't done automatically during a Build, but its no good complaining

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in VS2010 VB.NET, Thanks Rene! 
Unchecking project_properties.security.enable click once removed my problem

How my symptoms manifested:
I had a custom user control on a form, and was forced to remove any reference to it manually inside InitializeComponent() subroutine

reason: 
my  Winform had corrupted just after I modified the New() subroutine of my custom user control, where I changed the New() to add arg's and I didn't create a 'default' Sub New() with no arg's, as required for winform page rendering)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give closure on this question the following resolved it:

Unchecked the "enable clickonce security settings" checkbox in the security tab of the application properties.

As suggested by Rene in the comments of my question.